# Stick tableinfo to specific place in jqueryDatable

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

everybody!
I'm trying to stick tableInfo in jquery DataTable, like this[image]

But, when I chang value in show-list, the info slides down to the middle of column, like this[image]

I tried differnt variations of css to fix that, but I failed. now I use this code

```
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_info {
clear: both;
float: right;
margin-top: -510px;
margin-right: -550px;
```

Have you got any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: You mean, you want tableinfo to be placed in the header?

Comment: Yes. I want table info placed into header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `infoCallback` to generate the desired `a - b of z` layout :

```
var table = $("#example").DataTable({
   infoCallback: function(settings, start, end, max, total, pre) {
      return start+" - "+end+' of '+max;
   }
});
```

Move tableinfo to the first column of the table `#example` :

```
$(".dataTables_info").detach().appendTo($("#example th:first"));
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/zst02x5h/**